# Problem with File access permission in Google AppEngine with java "HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: java, file, google-app-engine, servlets, permissions

I am new in `AppEngine`

I tried to traite a file in my desktop with a servlet

I use this code

```
BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my source file") );
    weka.core.Instances train = new Instances (breader);
      breader.close();
```

'i hid source file there'

so I have in execution this Error

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /testservlet. Reason:

access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "source file derectory" "read")
Caused by:

Caused by:

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission"          "soure file derectory" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Could you please suggest, what is wrong with this?

Comment: Do you have a read permission for this file? And how is this related to App Engine?

Answer (score 0):

you can not access a file using java io classes it has been disabled

take look at this :

[bloblstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/)

Comment: Thanks for your response , can you give me a simple explication about  what i do for open  and read file in my desctop using  servlet with AppEngine, and what exactly blobstore API do